# MySQL | PARTITION BY Clause - Not working on XAMP

Tags: mysql

There is an article published by Geeks for Geeks on the MySQL Partition clause at https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mysql-partition-by-clause/.

But the same query not working after creating the same table in my XAAMP MySQL. It's giving me the syntax error to use near '(`partition by challenge_id....`)
Can anyone help?

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using? Partition by is relatively new.

Comment: Server version: 5.7.24 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the issue is your mysql version. the partition by is in version 5.7 and the dense_rank() can be use only in version 8.
try to use mysql v8 and it will be work fine
[DB_Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jCx8TZKMUyFZuZUNRKNnzK/0)

Comment: My shared server also doesn't have version 8. Is there any alternate query you suggest for the same result for version 5.7.

Comment: I'm not sure but you can try this link https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dobKKHAR2D2Z9KQvcsRsa2/0